# Single java web application, multi static files

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, web

I've made a very simple Java web application for Landing pages management. This application can generate some reports and get form submission data from static HTML files by Ajax (I do not generate any HTML dynamically). Each landing page is totally different that the others (different design, theme, ...) but they all are just static files. I also we have different domain for each Landing page.
So, for 50 Landing page, I need to, make copy of my web application, copy HTMLs, make new WAR file, make new Virtual Host (in tomcat for example), and finally deploy it!!!

I want to know that is there any way to I have 50 domain, 1 single web application and 50 different folder for static files. for  example:

```
ROOT (Web application root directory)
  sub1.domain1.com (directory)
  sub2.domain1.com (directory)
  domain2.com (directory)
  domain3.com (directory)
  ...
```

Everytime that I visit http://sub1.domain1.com, static files load from **sub1.domain1.com** folder and so on.

Comment: Can't you just redirect the domains to the subfolders of your application?

Comment: Maybe I can rewrite URLs with http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/ but I'm wondering if someone has better solution